# How can I assign clipboard text to a variable in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, variables, clipboard, assign

I've written a program that highlights numbers and copies them. I would like to be able to do some basic math with the copied text, such as multiplication or addition, but I can't figure out how to assign the clipboard data to a variable. Basically, I would like to be able to copy a number, assign it to variable "a", then repeat with variable "b" and multiply the two together. I have figured out how to select and copy the number so that part isn't an issue. Any help would be appreciated, even a completely different approach than what I have tried.

Here is my latest attempt at the problem:

```
    HANDLE clip0;
    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    EmptyClipboard();
        clip0 = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
     variable = (char)clip0;
    CloseClipboard();
```

where "variable" is the variable.

Whenever I run the program and tell it to output "variable", it returns the value of 0.

another attempt I made was this:

```
HANDLE clip1;
    if (OpenClipboard(NULL)) 
        clip1 = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
     variable = (char)clip1;
    CloseClipboard();
```

but "variable" would always take on the value of -8

Comment: When you say "C++", you presumably mean "Win32 API"?

Comment: This is not part of the language, but rather a OS service. Tag it so that people can answer for the *right* OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text content of the clipboard is a c-string pointed to by c.

```
if(OpenClipboard(NULL) != FALSE)
{
  HANDLE clip0 = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT); 
  if(clip0 != NULL)
  {
    char *c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(GlobalLock(clip0));
    // Use c before it goes out of scope
    ...
    GlobalUnlock(clip0);
  }
  CloseClipboard();
}
```

Comment: Surely you meant `char* x = (char*) h` on line 4?  Also `h` should be of type `void*`, not `HANDLE`; it's just a coincidence that `HANDLE` is typedef'ed to `void*`, but you should treat it as an opaque type.

Answer (score 7):

You need to call `GlobalLock(clip0)` to get a pointer to the data, rather than casting the handle. Then, when you're done, call `GlobalUnlock` to release the pointer.

```
OpenClipboard(NULL);
HANDLE clip0 = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
char* p=(char*)GlobalLock(clip0);
variable=*p;
GlobalUnlock(clip0);
CloseClipboard();
```

Comment: You probably want to convert the string to an integer with either `sscanf` or `strtol`, as opposed to just taking the first character of the string.

Comment: Yes --- I just borrowed the assignment of a single character from the question.

Comment: I apologize for mistakes I made, I'm kind of new to this. I did mean Win32 API. Adam was right, I did need to convert the string to an integer. I used sscanf and Anthony's suggestion and it seems to have worked well.

Thanks to everyone for your help.